# Finding the rate of the length of shadow.

Tags: calculus

*Question:* A man $1.5$ m tall is walking at a speed of $2$m/s away from a lamppost which has a lamp $5$m above the ground. Find the rate at which the length of the man’s shadow is increasing.

Let the length of the man’s shadow be “x”.

The height of the man is $1.5$m.

Let the distance between the base of the lamppost and the tip of the man’s shadow be “s”.

Using similar triangles,

${\frac{x}{1.5}} = {\frac{s}{5}}$

So, $x = \frac{(1.5)(s)}{5}$

I don’t know how to continue.

Comment: differentiate with respect to time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this question, you can make $s = x+y$, where y is the distance between the man and the lamppost. Therefore, by similar triangles, as you correctly mentioned:

$$x = \frac{1.5(x+y)}{5}\Rightarrow 0.7x = 0.3y \Rightarrow x = \frac{3}{7}y$$

Thus, to find the rate of increase of the man's shadow length, you can differentiate this relation with respect to time, noting that $\frac{dy}{dt} = 2$, since the man is moving away from the lamppost at a velocity of $2ms^{-1}$.

Hope this helps.